# MySQL SELECT two tables while substituting the values of a first table's field with the values of the second table's field

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database

I am building a simple bus ticket reservation system and I am facing the following problem: I have two tables in my MySQL database, `destinations` and `lines`. This is their structure:

```
+------------------+  +---------------------------------------------------+
|   destinations   |  |                        lines                      |
+--+---------------+  +--+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+
|id|      name     |  |id| dest_from | dest_to | depart_time | drive_time |
+--+---------------+  +--+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+
|1 | Boston        |  |1 |     1     |    2    |    08:00    |  06:00:00  |
|2 | New York City |  |2 |     1     |    3    |    08:00    |  04:00:00  |
|3 | Chicago       |  |3 |     1     |    4    |    08:00    |  04:00:00  |
|4 | Miami         |  |4 |     2     |    1    |    13:00    |  06:00:00  |
+--+---------------+  |5 |     2     |    3    |    13:00    |  06:00:00  |
                      |6 |     2     |    4    |    13:00    |  04:00:00  |
                      |7 |     3     |    1    |    11:00    |  04:00:00  |
                      |8 |     3     |    2    |    11:00    |  06:00:00  |
                      |9 |     3     |    4    |    11:00    |  06:00:00  |
                      |10|     4     |    1    |    09:00    |  04:00:00  |
                      |11|     4     |    2    |    09:00    |  04:00:00  |
                      |12|     4     |    3    |    09:00    |  06:00:00  |
                      +--+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

So, as you can see, I use the IDs of the `destinations`, written in the `lines` table on `dest_from` and `dest_to`.

The interface of the application allows the user to select departure point and arrival point, and after clicking "Search" the application has to `SELECT * FROM lines` where `dest_from` and `dest_to` equal the destinations, selected by the user.

So my question is: How to select and "tie up" both tables with a single SQL query, so I can get something like `Line number 1, from Boston to New York City, departs at 08:00 from Boston and will be in New York City at 14:00.` (08:00 + drive time of 06:00 hours = 14:00).

Should I use `JOIN` and if so, how the query should look?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes.  You use `JOIN`, twice.

Comment: OK, but what would the query look like, as I am having TWO fields in `lines` table, dependent on ONE field of `destinations` table?

Comment: @EmilAvramov Yes, You should have to use `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make two inner joins with the same table destinations like

```
select d1.name as from_city, d2.name as to_city from lines
inner join destinations d1 on d1.id = lines.dest_from
inner join destinations d2 on d2.id = lines.dest_to
```

Comment: yes u r right, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two joins, one on each field. Like this'ish:

```
SELECT from.name AS 'from' , to.name AS 'to', depart_time, drive_time
LEFT INNER JOIN destinations to ON  dest.id = dest_to
LEFT INNER JOIN destinations from ON  dest.id = dest_from
```

*(untested pseudo SQL, that should give you the idea)*

Comment: **Note:** To get the destination *time*, you can use a date add type function in your query, but not what the question was about so figured you'd find that out elsewhere 